# failed to display the video on page using video tag of HTML

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I am building an Angular js project where I am calling an API and that API is giving me list of URL's of Youtube videos.  I need to display those videos on my page so that if I will click on the play button then my video get started.

I have fetched the URL and I am trying to use `*ngFor` for iterating the array that I got. 
My HTML code is below

```
   <tr *ngFor="let fetchApi of fetchApi.data.featured">
        <td ></td>
        <td> {{fetchApi.id | json}} </td>
       <td> {{fetchApi.video_id| json}} </td>
       <td><video src="{{fetchApi.video_location}}" controls></video></td>
   </tr>
```

but I am getting the URL's from second td, but video tag is not working. Just showing the play button, not the video.

Can you correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: use another name other than  `let fetchApi`

Comment: I did that, same problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<video width="800" [src] = "fetchApi?.video_location" controls>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**EDIT**

You need to sanitize the url as,

```
 this.safeSrc =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/c9F5kMUfFKk");
```

and corresponding template,

```
<iframe [class.thumbnail]="thumbnail" [src]="safeSrc" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen
      allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnthrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

btw, thanks for giving this challenging task :P

Comment: tried this also. Same problem is there @Sajeetharan

Comment: can you post the video url

Comment: I am using component where I am fetching all the JSON as: `ngOnInit() {
     const scope = this;
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.fetchApi =data;
        console.log(this.fetchApi);
        //this.fetchApi = data;
      });
  };` How and where I should use `this.safeSrc =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/c9F5kMUfFKk");` I am dealing with array of URL's.

Comment: just assign this.fetchApi.video_location

Comment: Not getting it. Can you give an example ? My component code is: 


  `export class FetchApiComponent implements OnInit {

 fetchApi:  FetchApi;

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    

  }

  ngOnInit() {
     const scope = this;
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.fetchApi =data;
        console.log(this.fetchApi);
        


 });
  };
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<video ng-src="{{fetchApi.video_location}}" controls></video>
```

Have you tried ng-src instead of src.

Comment: I had tried `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{fetchApi.video_id| json}}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>` but still I am facing the same problem